# Python Flask Render Text from Variable like render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-2.x

I know the flask function `render_template`. I have to give the file name of the template. But now I want to render the string of a template (that is the content of the template). That makes sense. but I don't want to explain now why. How can I render the text of a template simply?

Comment: Just open the template file and return it as a string.

Comment: But if i do that (i have flask-bootstrap extension installed) it will give me these things: {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %} etc. as plain text and not handled.

Comment: Is that not your question? _How can I render the text of a template simply?_

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't handle the things in {...}

Comment: So i want a simple solution not a simple template

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [`render_template_string`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.render_template_string):

```
>>> from flask import render_template_string
>>> render_template_string('hello {{ what }}', what='world')
'hello world'
```

Comment: this answer gives an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'

Comment: @SharvariGc  in that case you need to use it inside a context: `with app.app_context(): ...`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927259/11750716

Answer (score 3):

you can use [from_string](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string)

```
template = "text {{ hello }}"
print app.jinja_env.from_string(template).render(hello='Hello')

>> text Hello
```

Comment: Since he's using Flask he can just use `render_template_string` (imported from Flask)

Comment: I can't tick both answers as right. Your answer is good too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can call jinja2 render function directly:

```
jinja2.Template("I am {{ var }}").render(**kargs)
```

When not working with flask, this is useful

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way without requiring Flask

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python).

```
import cgi
rendered = render_template('template.html')
return cgi.escape(rendered)
```

Comment: What has HTML escaping to do with this question?

Comment: This returns the rendered HTML file template as a string. The other answers just do simple template strings. @ThiefMaster