# How to add a favicon to a Flask route on Google colab without uploading a favicon file?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, favicon, ngrok

I would like to add a favicon to a route (`/`) on my Flask app on Google Colab, so that it will stop sending a second GET request which returns a 404.

How do I go about doing this?

I have seen various posts but they all include HTML files while I would like to do it on Google Colab itself without uploading the image every time?

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: You want to do this *without* uploading/storing an actual favicon.ico?

Comment: Hi @GinoMempin, yeap, will that be possible? Because google colab will not store the image there permanently. Is it possible to use a link for favicon.ico instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Google Colab and you don't want to upload or store any static HTML files or favicon.ico files, you can just [return an entire HTML page from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33402163/2745495), then have a `<head>` block with a link to some favicon file.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  

# Here I'm using a favicon.ico of a pizza from some random generator site
FAVICON_URL='https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-17/50e4281252565f8fc85151c075d4e937.ico'

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    content='Hello!'
    return render_template_string(f'''<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="{FAVICON_URL}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{content}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

That gets rid of the 404 on `/favicon` (and actually displays an icon):

[image: using external favicon]

If you don't care about displaying an actual icon, you can try just leaving it "empty" with `href="data:,"` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917888/2745495) from this post [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/2745495):

```py
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    content='Hello!'
    return render_template_string(f'''<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{content}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
''')
```

[image: using empty favicon]

Both solutions seem to work on

- Google Colab
- Flask 1.1.2 and flask-ngrok 0.0.25
- Firefox 88 and Chrome 90 on macOS

A possible issue here is having to maintain an entire HTML page as an inline string which can be insecure and cumbersome (["*Generating HTML from within Python is not fun*"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates)). I don't know how complex a web app you are planning to make. It makes sense on Google Colab, but using a setup with a static HTML file (+ Jinja templating) could be more maintainable.

Comment: Hi Gino! Thanks so much for your detailed answer, this was exactly what I was looking for! I'm really new to html and api's so I wasn't sure about how to incorporate the answers which I have found on many previously asked ones into my program. So your answer really cleared up my questions! Thank you very much!!