# How to redirect to another function with the use of a variable value in flask?

Tags: python, flask

The error:

```
line 136, in render_template
   ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

The app.route:

```
@app.route('/congratulations')
def congratulations():
    return render_template('congratulations.html')
```

To redirect to this template I used:

```
redirect('/congratulations')
and
congratulations()
```

(None of them are working)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full error.

Comment: Maybe try using `url_for`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478366/create-dynamic-urls-in-flask-with-url-for#7478705

Comment: An explanation on [why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17209173/11323371)

Answer (score 0):

Let me write down examples I used

> return redirect(url_for('main.login'))

> return redirect('/')

> return redirect(f'/store/{store_id}')

This is a reference.
https://python-commandments.org/flask-redirect/
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.redirect

I hope it helps.